openapi generator and oneOf, What is the best way to implement OAS using oneOf
i am currently trying to implement an openapi specification which uses the oneOf component. The way its setup, there is a Grandparent which has a property Children which can be one of either Child or GrandChild. The Child and GrandChild furthermore both have a property Address which can be one of either LocalAddress or InternationalAddress. When i use the openApiGenerator i get a Children interface and two concrete classes namely Child and GrandChild which implement the interface similarly, i have an interface Address and two concrete classes LocalAddress and InternationalAddress which implement the interface. The issue i am currently facing is in the implementation of these specs, i am trying to generate the relevant class either Child or GrandChild - LocalAddress or InternationalAddress and i am not sure how best to go about this.
This is the first time i am implementing a OAS which uses a oneOf component so im not sure the best way to approach this implementation. Currently i tried to solve generating the relevant classes as follows;
private void creatChildOrGrandChild(GrandParent grandparent){

    if(grandParent.getChildren().getClass().equals(Child.class)){

        ChildModel childModel = objectMapper.convertValue(grandParent.getChildren(), Child.class);
        ChildEntity childEntity = createChildEntity(childModel);
        ChildEntity savedChildEntity = childRepository.save(childEntity);

        if (savedChildEntity.getAddres().getClass().equals(LocalAddres.class)){
            LocalAddresModel localAddresModel = objectMapper.convertValue(childModel.getAddres(), LocalAddresModel.class);
            LocalAddressEntity localAddressEntity = createLocalAddressEntity(localAddresModel);
            localAddressRepository.save(localAddressEntity);
        } else {
            AddresInternationalModel addresInternationalModel = objectMapper.convertValue(childModel.getAddres(), AddresInternationalModel.class);
            AddresInternationalEntity addressInternationalEntity = createInternationalAddressEntity(addresInternationalModel);
            addressInternationalRepository.save(addressInternationalEntity);
        }

    } else {
        GrandChildModel grandChildModel = objectMapper.convertValue(grandParent.getChildren(), GrandChild.class);
        GrandChildEntity grandChildEntity = createGrandChildEntity(grandChildModel);
        GrandChildEntity savedGrandChildEntity = grandChildRepository.save(grandChildEntity);

        if (savedGrandChildEntity.getAddres().getClass().equals(LocalAddres.class)){
            LocalAddresModel localAddresModel = objectMapper.convertValue(grandChildModel.getAddres(), LocalAddresModel.class);
            LocalAddressEntity localAddressEntity = createLocalAddressEntity(localAddresModel);
            localAddressRepository.save(localAddressEntity);
        } else {
            AddresInternationalModel addresInternationalModel = objectMapper.convertValue(grandChildModel.getAddres(), AddresInternationalModel.class);
            AddresInternationalEntity addressInternationalEntity = createInternationalAddressEntity(addresInternationalModel);
            addressInternationalRepository.save(addressInternationalEntity);
        }
    }
}

Obviously there is a lot of repetition in the code and i am not entirely sure whether this way of generating the oneOf class is the best approach. Hence i would like to ask firstly, is this the way to go when generating the relevant class of the OneOf component? Secondly, if this is a viable approach, is there a way i can refactor this code to avoid the code duplication?
